# How do you export accepted meeting attendees in Outlook

Tags: ms-office, calendar

At my job, I organize large meetings (100+). At the end, I need a list of the email addresses of the people who accepted the invite. How do you export this list from Outlook on a Mac? I know it's possible on a Windows machine.

What I really want is some sort of **Meeting > Right Click > Attendees > Accepted > Export**

I'd even settle for **Meeting > Right Click > Attendees > Accepted > Reply All**

Answer (score 0):

This is not pretty, but it works.

1. Create a search filter so you can easily select all the "Accepted: ${Event Name}" emails.
2. Select them all.
3. Right click and choose "Categorize" and choose any color you do not already use.
4. Go to File -> Export
5. Under "What do you want to export?" choose "Items in the category", then choose the color you chose in the previous step.
6. Click "Continue"
7. Save the `.olm` file some where you can find it.
8. Rename the `.olm` file to `.txt`
9. Open the `.txt` file in Excel
10. Sort the first column alphabetically
11. Scroll way down until you see the rows that start with `ATTENDEE;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED;`
12. Copy those rows to your favorite text editor
13. Find and replace until you just have the email addresses. If your text editor support regex then you can set Find to `ATTENDEE;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED;CN=".*":MAILTO:` and then leave the Replace field empty.
14. Done.